# Alternative for TCategoryPanelGroup or TPageControl

Tags: delphi, panel, categories

Does an alternative exist for TCategoryPanelGroup or TPageControl? My problem is I use a CategoryPanelGroup on a PageControl, therefore there is an enormous flicker which I can not prevent (using DoubleBuffered, disabling a ParentBackground and other things).

I use TPageControl as panels, to show/hide groups of controls.

Comment: You need to address the flicker rather than change the control. I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: @David: Since this control is implemented entirely in Delphi, I am not 100 % sure you can rely on its quality.

Comment: @ David Heffernan, I used everything what I could. Do you know the solution of the flicker?

Comment: @Andreas There may well be a way. I'd guess that the flicker is down to the erase background on the tab sheet. If the category panel fills the tab sheet then this erase background can be skipped. But it all depends on the layout of the form.

Comment: @maxfax I don't know the cause of the flicker, let alone the solution to it! This has the hallmarks of an XY question.

Comment: Why aren't you asking if there's an alternative to using a Page control?

Comment: @Warren P, if there's an alternative to using a Page control?

Comment: @maxsince you aren't using with the tabs showing you can just swap it out for panels that you show and hide

Comment: @ David Heffernan, did you mean to use TPanel? I am using TabSheets with TabVisible=false now. May be I understood not exactly.

Comment: I see the good way to use a PageControl instead of a CategoryPanelGroup (not the same visual effect...but it is better than buggy CategoryPanelGroup) and set DoubleBuffered for the PageControl, TabSheets and use a StaticText instead of Lables.

Comment: Although handy at design time, a TPageControl is not designed to be used as you you are using it. I would use for example frames, or panels kept hidden but one.

Comment: Frames are good. But for me they are tricky. It will be my next question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to show tabs, don't use a page control.

Comment: now .... do it without the page control. Just flip visibility on the frames, using your own function MakeFrameVisible(x:Frame)